# How to modify a struct content through 2 layer of functions?

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following code:

```
typedef otherStruct_t struct_t[X][Y];

void foo1(struct_t * mystruct); //declaration in main()
main()
{
   struct_t mystruct = {0};
   foo1(&mystruct);
   ...
}
void foo1(struct_t * mystruct)
{
   foo2(&mystruct, number);
   ...
}
```

in other .c file.

```
void foo2(struct_t ** mystruct, int number)
{
   (*mystruct[x][y])-> number = number;
}
```

I read some posts regarding pointer of pointer in struct and this what I came up with.
It compiles, but the caller struct is not modified, and sometime cause seg. fault as well.
Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Generally speaking, typedeffing an array like this is best avoided, because the resulting code can be extremely confusing...

Comment: foo1 --> struct_t **  , foo2 ---> struct_t ***

Comment: please bare with me. That's how I learned it from school and got used to it already :p

Comment: Anyway, you probably want `(**mystruct)[x][y]`.  `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik , how would I pass a mystruct to foo1 then?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to do it.  In the following code you can remove the comment around

```
#define NO_PTR_USE 1
```

to do it without using pointer(s). If using pointers, then you have to remember as @Oli Charlesworth pointed out, [] has higher precedence than *.

```
/* #define NO_PTR_USE 1  */

#define X       10
#define Y       10

#define ax      1
#define ay      5

struct foo {
    int number;
};

typedef struct foo struct_t[X][Y];

void
#if NO_PTR_USE
    foo1(struct_t mystruct),
    foo2(struct_t mystruct, int x, int y, int n);
#else
    foo1(struct_t *mystruct),
    foo2(struct_t *mystruct, int x, int y, int n);
#endif

main()
{
    struct_t mystruct = {0};

#if NO_PTR_USE
    foo1(mystruct);
    printf("No pointer was used.\n");
#else                         
    foo1(&mystruct);
    printf("Pointer was used.\n");
#endif                        
    printf("mystruct[%d][%d].number = %d\n",
            ax, ay, mystruct[ax][ay].number);
}

void
#if NO_PTR_USE
foo1(struct_t mystruct)
#else                 
foo1(struct_t *mystruct)
#endif                 
{
    foo2(mystruct, ax, ay, 1234);
}

void
#if NO_PTR_USE
foo2(struct_t mystruct, int x, int y, int n)
#else
foo2(struct_t *mystruct, int x, int y, int n)
#endif
{
#if NO_PTR_USE
    mystruct[x][y].number = n;
#else
    (*mystruct)[x][y].number = n;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, once you've got a pointer, you don't pass it by address.  Think of `FILE *fp = fopen(...);`.  You don't use `fprintf(&fp, ...);`, do you?

Same here:

```
typedef struct foo struct_t[X][Y];  // Nasty piece of work - don't do it!

extern void foo1(struct_t *t);
extern void foo2(struct_t *t);

int main(void)
{
    struct_t data = {0};

    ...
    foo1(&data);
    ...
    return 0;
}

void foo1(struct_t *t)
{
    ...
    foo2(t);
    ...
}
```

Other file:

```
void foo2(struct_t *t)
{
    ...
    stuct foo x = (*t)[i][j];
    ...
}
```

Note that a `struct_t` is a 2D array of structures, so a `struct_t *` is a pointer to an array of structures.  Therefore, you have to get the access notation correct, as shown in `foo2()` above.  And that's one reason why you probably don't want to use that type.  You'd be better off, almost certainly, using:

```
typedef struct bar
{
    struct foo data[X][Y];
} bar;
```

And you can then pass `bar *bp` values around, and access the data using `bp->data[i][j]`.